# Better way of displaying nested attributes in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to display only four `options` to `questions`. At present I am repeating the code four times. I am sure that there is a better way to do it. Can you please tell me how?

**form**

```
<%= form_for @question do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.build do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.check_box :is_answer, checked: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %> 

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.build do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.check_box :is_answer, checked: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.build do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.check_box :is_answer, checked: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.build do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.check_box :is_answer, checked: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here I am repeating the block for `:options` four times. How can I do it in a single block?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller your could do

```
def create
  @question = Question.new
  4.times { @question.options.build } 
end
```

And then in your view

```
<%= form_for @question do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.build do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.check_box :is_answer, checked: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

That *should* build 4 of the nested fields for you so you don't have to repeat the code that many times :D